# How to "group by" a list of objects by a class attribute in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have a linked list with nodes, each node contains Flight objects
which have several attributes (Origin city, Destination city, etc).

I want to build a list, in a similar manner to SQL's group by; for each origin city all the flights and their origins

I've tried storing cities in a list but I don't know how to initialise it, NetBeans says I can't and I don't know how to do it.

This is what I've got so far, last part is a comment since I don't know how to properly implement it.

```
public void PrintList() {
    NodeFlight aux = start;
    List<String> Ciudades;

    while (aux != null) {
        //add to the list cities if current.getcity isn't in the list already??
        //current=next;
    }

    //loop for each element in the city list
    //current=start;

    //loop if current equals to the first element of the list?
    //print each element which origin city is equals to the city list current index
    //close first loop

    //next city? i++? whatever
    //close bigger loop?
}
```

The format I'm looking for is something like:

```
"Origin city"
    1 - "Flight1"
    2 - "Flight2"
    ...
    N - "FlightN"
"Origin city"
    1.........
```

And so on.

Comment: Use a graph instead of a list, then all nodes with distance one are the destinations reachable without changing planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite an easy task using **Java8 Streams API**: stream your flights, and collect them with `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Let's say your flights look like this:

```
List<Flight> flights = new LinkedList<>();
flights.add(new Flight("Zurich", "London"));
flights.add(new Flight("Madrid", "London"));
flights.add(new Flight("Madrid", "Rome"));
flights.add(new Flight("Zurich", "New York"));
flights.add(new Flight("New York", "London"));
```

Find flights from/to each city:

```
Map<String, List<Flight>> flightsFromEachCity = 
    flights.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Flight::getCityFrom));

Map<String, List<Flight>> flightsToEachCity = 
    flights.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Flight::getCityTo));
```

Testing: print the outgoing and incoming flights for each city

```
System.out.println("OUTGOING:");
for (String city : flightsFromEachCity.keySet()) {
    String cities = flightsFromEachCity.get(city).stream().map(Flight::getCityTo).collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
    System.out.println("- from " + city + " to " + cities);
}
System.out.println("INCOMING:");
for (String city : flightsToEachCity.keySet()) {
    String cities = flightsToEachCity.get(city).stream().map(Flight::getCityFrom).collect(Collectors.joining(" and "));
    System.out.println("- from " + cities + " to " + city);
}
```

Output:

> OUTGOING:
>   - from New York to London
>   - from Madrid to London and Rome
>   - from Zurich to London and New York 
>   INCOMING:
>   - from Zurich to New York
>   - from Madrid to Rome
>   - from Zurich and Madrid and New York to London

Comment: this seems pretty handy indeed but I'm not completely familiar with it's functionality, I edited my question added my desired format, do you think I can achieve it with this?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that you want to sort a list of your custom object. I made some assumption  I did not create any node. I just made my operations on a simple flight object.

```
public class Flight  implements Comparable<Flight>{
    private String sourceCity;
    private String destinationCity;

    public Flight(String sourceCity,String destinationCity)
    {
        this.sourceCity=sourceCity;
        this.destinationCity=destinationCity;
    }

    public String getSourceCity() {
        return sourceCity;
    }

    public String getDestinationCity() {
        return destinationCity;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Flight o) {
        return (this.sourceCity.compareTo(o.getSourceCity()));
    }


}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Flight f1=new Flight("A","B");
    Flight f2=new Flight("B","C");
    Flight f3=new Flight("D","F");
    Flight f4=new Flight("AB","BC");
    Flight f5=new Flight("ZA","B");
    Flight f6=new Flight("YB","C");
    Flight f7=new Flight("C","ZA");
    Flight f8=new Flight("B","BC");
    Flight f9=new Flight("A","BB");
    Flight f10=new Flight("B","CE");
    Flight f11=new Flight("D","ZSA");
    Flight f12=new Flight("B","BVC");

    List<Flight> flightList=new ArrayList<Flight>();
    flightList.add(f1);
    flightList.add(f2);
    flightList.add(f3);
    flightList.add(f4);
    flightList.add(f5);
    flightList.add(f6);
    flightList.add(f7);
    flightList.add(f8);
    flightList.add(f9);
    flightList.add(f10);
    flightList.add(f11);
    flightList.add(f12);

    Collections.sort(flightList);

    for(Flight f:flightList)
    {
        System.out.println("Source city= "+f.getSourceCity()+" Destination city= "+f.getDestinationCity());
    }


}
```

And the output of the code will be

```
Source city= A Destination city= B
Source city= A Destination city= BB
Source city= AB Destination city= BC
Source city= B Destination city= C
Source city= B Destination city= BC
Source city= B Destination city= CE
Source city= B Destination city= BVC
Source city= C Destination city= ZA
Source city= D Destination city= F
Source city= D Destination city= ZSA
Source city= YB Destination city= C
Source city= ZA Destination city= B
```

I think it will help you..